# How to add menu in magento admin panel?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am looking for some advice or information on how to do the following. I want to add one more menu in magento admin panel. I am trying many ways but not working. How can i add extra one menu in admin panel. please advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am creating one module.

info - Company name folder

ExtendedMenu - Module Name

I am creating 2 new folders in modules folder.

etc & Block

etc folder I am creating config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Info_ExtendedMenu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Info_ExtendedMenu>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <configurable>
                <class>Info_Configurable_Block</class>
            </configurable>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <page_menu>Info_ExtendedMenu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu</page_menu>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <blocks>
            <configurable>
                <class>Inchoo_Configurable_Block</class>
            </configurable>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Block -- Adminhtml - Menu.php

```
<?php
class Info_ExtendedMenu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu
{
    public function getMenuArray()
    {
        //Load standard menu
        $parentArr = parent::getMenuArray();

        //Prepare "View Sites" menu
        $parentArr['view_sites'] = array(
            'label' => 'Web2Print',
            'active'=>false ,
            'sort_order'=>0,
            'click' => 'return false;',
            'url'=>'#',
            'level'=>0,
            'last'=> true,
            'children' => array()
        );

        $app = Mage::app();

        $j = 0;

        $allWebsites = $app->getWebsites();
        $totalWebsiteCount = count($allWebsites) - 1;

        foreach ($allWebsites as $_eachWebsiteId => $websiteVal){
            $_storeName = $app->getWebsite($_eachWebsiteId)->getName();
            $baseUrl = $app->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getUrl();
            $_websiteUrl = array(
                            'label' => 'View Admin',
                            'active' => false ,
                            'click' => "var extraurl='w2p/admin/index.php';alert(this.href+extraurl); window.open(this.href+extraurl, 'Website - '+ this.href); return false;",
                            'sort_order' => $i++ * 10,
                            'level' => 2,
                            'url' => $baseUrl
                            );

            if(count($parentArr['view_sites']['children']) == $totalWebsiteCount){
                $_websiteUrl['last'] = true;
            } else {
                $_websiteUrl['last'] = false;
            }

            $parentArr['view_sites']['children'][$j - 1] = $_websiteUrl;

            $allStores = $app->getWebsite($app->getWebsite($_eachWebsiteId)->getId())->getStores();
            $totalCount = count($allStores);
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val){
                $_websiteId = $app->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getWebsiteId();
                if($_websiteId == $j){
                    $_storeName = 'View Admin';
                    $baseUrl = $app->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getUrl();
                    $_websiteUrl = array(
                            'label' => $_storeName,
                            'active' => false ,
                            'click' => "var extraurl='w2p/admin/index.php';alert(this.href+extraurl); window.open(this.href+extraurl, 'Website - '+ this.href); return false;",
                            'sort_order' => $i++ * 10,
                            'level' => 2,
                            'url' => $baseUrl
                            );

                    if(count($parentArr['view_sites']['children'][$j - 1]['children']) + 1 == $totalCount or $totalCount == 0)
                        $_websiteUrl['last'] = true;
                        else
                        $_websiteUrl['last'] = false;

                    $parentArr['view_sites']['children'][$j - 1]['children'][$i] = $_websiteUrl;
                }
            }
        }
        return $parentArr;
    }
}
```

Also you need to go to magento base folder path app-etc-modules-youemodule name(Inchoo_ExtendedMenu.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_ExtendedMenu>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Inchoo_ExtendedMenu>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Menu creation over. cheers.

Comment: ,I don't know your answer works fine or not, because i didn't try this. but i have one doubt on your account. Please refer this site http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190267/why-does-this-user-have-posts-that-appear-to-be-older-than-their-account#190267

Comment: Hi @DRAJI your doubt is cleared? or check your link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190267/why-does-this-user-have-posts-that-appear-to-be-older-than-their-account#190267

Answer (score 6):

If this is your custom module what you need to do is in etc/config.xml add the following:

```
<adminhtml>
  <menu>
      <report>
        <children>
          <module name>
            <title>Title to show in the menu bar</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>Modules controller action</action>
          </module name>
        </children>
      </report>
    </menu>
 </adminhtml>
```

The example above will add a new item to the reports tab and trigger an action in the controller to do something. Hope this helps.

Comment: still applicable in 1.9

Answer (score 0):

You can add menu using custom module
the below tutorial help me a lot
please click [here](http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5)

Answer (score -1):

What menu? Are you talking about an extension?

In order to do that you have: `System > Magento connect > Magento connect manager`

**EDIT:**

Theres an extension to manage this, take a look: [Custom Menu Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-menu.html)

Comment: Hi @Flowen i need to create custom menu module in magento 1.7.0.2. How can i create module please advise

Comment: Edited, look this extension

Comment: I am installed in magento v 1.7.0.2 but Fatal error: Class 'WP_CustomMenu_Helper_Data' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547 please guide me

Comment: Have you log out and log in from the admin panel after installing the extension? If still crashes, see the product review or support, because I dont know what exactly is happening. There is always somebody with this kind of problems at installing.

Comment: Maybe it conflicts with some other module... need to rewrite another block, by adding this on its config.xml: `<blocks>
<page>
<rewrite>
<html_topmenu>WP_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation</html_topmenu>
</rewrite>
</page>
</blocks>`

Comment: Hi @Flowen, This is a front panel custom menu. but i need to add menu in admin panel near by system menu. please help me...

Comment: This should be a comment