# Magento control panel "Product Information" menu modify

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I'm developing a custom store pickup module for a customer Magento store and I need to add the Menu child "Pickup availability" on the product information menu on product management.

How can I do this? I've looking on `Mage_Catalog adminhtml.xml`[image]

file but I didn't find anything helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add menu in magento admin panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186418/how-to-add-menu-in-magento-admin-panel)

Comment: Isn't the same problem, on that question the user is asking for add an option in the main dashboard menu